# Ошибка при создании Ini файла

Tags: java, файлы, ini

Начинаю заниматься библиотекой для работы с .INI файлами и сразу возникла трудность, а именно сложность заключается в том, что не находит:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\projects\yourBudgetApp\saves\settings.ini (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:212)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:154)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:109)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:86)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:184)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1167)
    at org.ini4j.spi.IniSource.<init>(IniSource.java:55)
    at org.ini4j.spi.AbstractParser.newIniSource(AbstractParser.java:68)
    at org.ini4j.spi.IniParser.parse(IniParser.java:67)
    at org.ini4j.Ini.load(Ini.java:119)
    at org.ini4j.Ini.load(Ini.java:114)
    at org.ini4j.Ini.load(Ini.java:99)
    at org.ini4j.Wini.<init>(Wini.java:49)
    at com.company.yourBudgetApp.main(yourBudgetApp.java:17)
```

Хотя указываю верный путь: 
**input**

```
File file = new File("saves/settings.ini");
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

**output**

```
E:\projects\yourBudgetApp\saves\settings.ini
```

Но при создании Wini файла выскакивает эта ошибка: 
**input**

```
File file = new File("saves/settings.ini");
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
Wini ini = new Wini(file);
```

**output**

```
E:\projects\yourBudgetApp\saves\settings.ini
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\projects\yourBudgetApp\saves\settings.ini (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:212)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:154)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:109)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:86)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:184)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1167)
    at org.ini4j.spi.IniSource.<init>(IniSource.java:55)
    at org.ini4j.spi.AbstractParser.newIniSource(AbstractParser.java:68)
    at org.ini4j.spi.IniParser.parse(IniParser.java:67)
    at org.ini4j.Ini.load(Ini.java:119)
    at org.ini4j.Ini.load(Ini.java:114)
    at org.ini4j.Ini.load(Ini.java:99)
    at org.ini4j.Wini.<init>(Wini.java:49)
    at com.company.yourBudgetApp.main(yourBudgetApp.java:17)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Заранее спасибо за вашу помощь )

Comment: Ну если этого файла может не быть, то его наверное необходимо предварительно создать посредством `file.createNewFile();`.

Comment: А вы уверенны, что он уже существует? Что делает класс `Wini` в конструкторе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего самого файла нет в конечной точке и его нужно создать, попробуйте так

```
File file = new File("saves/settings.ini");
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    file.createNewFile();
}
Wini ini = new Wini(file);
```

Comment: Самое веселое, что файл уже существовал и лежал в той директории, но после добавления вашего предложенного кода, ошибка не выскочила, странно однако... Ну в любом спасибо большое всем )

Comment: Видимо структура была не подходящая